# How to make a camera overlay on an image as attached?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I want to make imageview for user profile as attached to this question if anybody[image] knows any library or any other solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Anchor view .One way to do it with `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_ProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_Camera"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```